# Java: Get access from nested class to main class?

Tags: java, nested-class

Code:

```
public class A{
  B b = new B();

  public class B{
    public void fun(){ send(A); }
  }
```

I want to do something with all A object in B. 
I can create method in A class:

```
private A getThis(){return this;}
```

But is it other solution (some keyword)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code inside your inner class.

```
A.this
```

It should give you a reference to the enclosing instance from the outer class.

Here is a small example.

```
public class A {
    private B b = new B();

    public class B {
        public void fun() {

        }
        public A getEnclosing(){
            return A.this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a == a.b.getEnclosing());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
B b = new B(this);
```

Then B contructor

```
public B(A a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

Comment: like my idea. Not pretty ;)